# CXF Interceptor phase for cleaning up MDC

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, slf4j, logback

Do you have a recommendation for which Apache CXF phase to hook an outbound interceptor to clean up the SLF4J Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)?

I see some [code available publicly on GitHub](https://github.com/dtag-dbu/psikeds/blob/master/Common/src/main/java/org/psikeds/common/interceptor/CleanupInterceptor.java) that fires the clearing of the logging context at the `Phase.PRE_STREAM`. My first thought was to call it at the very last `Phase.SETUP_ENDING`.

**EDIT:** After deploying it I realized that I also needed to wire it to `outFaultInterceptors`. To get that to work I had to change `Phase.SETUP_ENDING` to `Phase.MARSHALL`. But I have no idea why or whether that's the best phase.

I'm new to Apache CXF and want to make sure I don't break something using the wrong phase.

Here's my code

```
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.slf4j.MDC;

public class MdcCleanUpInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    public MdcCleanUpInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.MARSHAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        MDC.clear();
    }
}
```

and my Spring definition

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">
    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="mdcCleanUpInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="mdcCleanUpInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus>

    <bean id="mdcCleanUpInterceptor" class="MdcCleanUpInterceptor"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: If anyone knows of good documentation on the interceptor phases, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone with `POST_MARSHALL`. This way the MDC is still in context when the outputs go through marshall phase and it still works as an `outFaultInterceptor`, too.

Comment: I had a problem with `POST_MARSHAL`, there was a WARN in my log:
`o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain      : Skipping interceptor my.company.MDCOutputInterceptor: Phase post-marshal specified does not exist.`
And the most available phase in my case was `PRE_PROTOCOL`.
But I have a feeling :) that it's not a good idea to use phases after `POST_LOGICAL` for processing business logic cases.